# How to check if the reycast has stoped hitting a object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, onmouseover, onmousedown

I Want it to set the material back to the material i setup when the reycast isint hitting the  object anymore i only want it to be the hightlight material when its hitting it, Thanks in advance

```
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
    rayPoint.y = 2;
    transform.position = rayPoint;


    //  Debug.Log("m: " + Input.mousePosition); 
    //  Debug.Log("r: " + rayPoint);

    RaycastHit hit;

    Ray BoardCheck = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);

    if (Physics.Raycast(BoardCheck, out hit))
    {


        if (hit.collider.tag == "BoardBlock")
        {
           // Debug.Log("Hit" + hit.collider.gameObject);
            RaycastHitObject = hit.collider.gameObject;


            RaycastHitObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = Hilight;
        }

    }

    
}

//IF MORE INFO IS NEEDED JUST ASK
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A simple if else should do. If you hit your object, change its appearance, if not, change it back. All you need to do is to keep a reference to the object. Assign it via the inspector or inside the if on first hit. You already seem to be doing it (`RaycastHitObject`) but don't seem to make use of it.

```
// Target gameobject to change material of
GameObject target;

RaycastHit hit;
Ray BoardCheck = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);

// Perform raycast
if (Physics.Raycast(BoardCheck, out hit))
{
    // Compare collider tag
    if (hit.collider.tag == "BoardBlock")
    {
        // Keep reference
        target = hit.collider.gameObject;

        // Change material
        target.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = highlightMat;
    }
    else
    {
        // Change back material
        target.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = nonHighlightMat;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still need to check if `target` is assigned and reset so you don't every frame change it's material or get null ref exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You need to **store** the hit target

Before coming to that personally I would use a dedicated component like e.g.

```
public class Focusable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;

    private Material idleMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private Material focusedMaterial;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        idleMaterial = _renderer.material;
    }

    private bool isFocused;
    public bool IsFocused
    {
        get => _isFocused;
        set
        {
            _isFocused = value;
            _renderer.material = value ? focusedMaterial : idleMaterial;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your controller do

```
// Stores the currently hit object
private Focusable currentTarget;

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    // I will just trust that you know what you do with those rays
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    var rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
    rayPoint.y = 2;
    transform.position = rayPoint;

    var BoardCheck = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);
  
    if (Physics.Raycast(BoardCheck, out var hit) 
        // instead of the tag you can now directly check for the component
        // as this is optional you could of course also just stick to the tag if you want to 
        && hit.collider.TryGetComponent<Focusable>(out var focusable))
    {
        // -> we are hitting one of our objects 

        // if it is still the same as before we don't need to do anything 
        if (currentTarget != focusable)
        {
            if(currentTarget)
            {
                // did we hit  another one before? -> unfocus
                currentTarget.IsFocused = false;
            }

            // now focus and store this hit target once
            currentTarget = focusable;
            currentTarget.IsFocused = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // we don't hit a focusable at all 
    
        if (currentTarget)
        {
            // if there was a previous hit unfocus it once
            currentTarget.IsFocused = false;
            currentTarget = null;
        }
    }
}
```